# Why isn't my React app showing in GitHub Pags?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, hosting, github-pages

I'm trying to deploy [my GitHub Repo](https://github.com/rafaelicastro/stem-club) to GitHub Pages at https://rafaelicastro.github.io/stem-club/, but nothing except the title & logo for the tab is loading. I've tried everything suggested in other questions, but nothing is working. What should I do?

Comment: Refer to this [video](https://youtu.be/2hM5viLMJpA) to help you.

Comment: I've followed all the steps in the video, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I think your react-router is not properly configured. You deploy your app to a non-root path (/stem-club), so it doesn't match to your routing locations (/, /physics and /math).
That's why you see a blank page and no errors in a console – everything is working normally, you just didn't define any component for a path "/stem-club".
You have to set a basename for the router so that it will understand what is your actual root path @_@

Comment: HI! Sorry, I'm relatively new to React, and I can't figure out how exactly to implement this. I've tried looking it up, but would you mind explaining this to me in more detail? Thank you so much!